# Selenium webdriver to get the visible text of a website on android

Tags: android, .net, selenium-webdriver, maui

So my problem is, i wrote a code to get the visible text of a website's data, it runs perfectly on desktop but android cannot handle it (I wrote it in .Net maui). Any web scraping does not work for the site for example with the Html Agility pack. This is the code that i want to "convert" to android:

```
static string GetVisibleTextFromUrl(string url)
{
    // Set up Selenium 
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

    // Wait for the page to load 
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

    // Extract visible text
    string visibleText = 
    driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).Text;

    // Close 
    driver.Quit();

    return visibleText;
}
```

Is there any way to do it?

Tried a lot of ways mainly with html agility pack but that did not worked. Also if I open the web page source and I search for the text with ctrl+f it does not show up, only the href tag for it, but I can see it on the site.